# Javascript syntax error for innerHTML Text

Tags: javascript, html

document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "Please Remove "live:" then press enter";

What is wrong in it, I am getting an error here

Comment: Take a look at the syntax highlighting in your code. Do you see any problems?

Comment: its not giving any error but its only redirecing to the pagename i gave in form action=searchquery.php
and this page is just blank, nothing shows up

Comment: @AtifSheikh It is probably giving you an error, but since you are using a form the browser redirects you to the new page after you press enter.

Comment: i actually tried the word live without semicolon just to check if semicolon is creating an issue, so i checked only live with (0, 4) but it is still not performing any action and redirecting to the action page with blank result on it

Comment: since it's not clicking: *cough* quote escaping *cough*

Comment: The problem is that you forgot to escape your double quotes, not the semicolon.

Comment: *"What am I missing"* ... using a code linter....in your IDE or online to find syntax errors

Comment: yes semicolon was't issue but double quotes were ending the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substring test is almost certainly working.

I believe you have a syntax error with your quotations.
`document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "Please Remove "live:" then press enter";`

Should be
`document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "Please Remove 'live:' then press enter";`

The " before live: ends that string and causes a compilation error, because JS doesn't know what to do with live:.

Comment: Perfectly fine. my Gosh, i did not notice this small mistake, Thanks a bunch Mr Nick Graham, you saved my full night :)

Comment: a liitle more help required if you could help. I am already using this code
        if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-.,_]+$/.test(x)){
        alert("invalid name"); } 

so now when i check for this word **live:**
I want to give another alert about this specific word **live:** 

but surely when user puts live: it gives an error of Invalid Name because of special character validation check already put on it. what should i do

Comment: @AtifSheikh Have you considered using an IDE? Simple errors like this shouldn't take you a full night to find.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Sir, i am totally a newbie in javascript and php, So i honestly did not know about IDE, i will just google it and will find how can i be good with it

Comment: @AtifSheikh depends on what exactly you are wanting to happen. You need to structure your if/else's correctly. If you want the *live:* alert to show and not the other you could do: `if (<live>) {...} else if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-.,_]+$/.test(x)) {...}`

Comment: @AtifSheikh Take a look at Sublime Text if you are new to programming.